# How to disable the Dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, ios6

I am using JqueryMobile-1.3.0 and cordova-2.1.0 for iOS app.I want to disable the dropdown dynamically
how to do that?I am doing like this
`$('#assignedToDropDown').attr('disabled', true);`
Using this it will become disable but it will look like active element means disable element css is not getting applied on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('select').selectmenu('disable');
```

Read more about it here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/methods.html

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dEXac/